# array for printing as json, array and xml

Tags: php, xml, json

I'm trying to get proper output in json format but my output below is a bit messy. It should be like this:
`"{"table":"users","operation":"select","username":"inan"}"`

How can I solve my problem?

Thanks

**server.php**

```
print_r($_POST);
```

**client.php**

```
$data = array('table'=>'users', 'operation'=>'select', 'uid'=>'yoyo');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$output = curl_exec($curl_handle);

if ($this->request_response_type == 'array')
{
echo $output;
}
else if ($this->request_response_type == 'json')
{
echo json_encode($output);
}
else if ($this->request_response_type == 'xml')
{
    //xml conversion will be done here later. not ready yet.
}
```

**output:**

```
"Array\n(\n    [table] => users\n    [operation] => select\n    [uid] => yoyo\n)\n"
```

Comment: the output you are showing is a print_r of a php array. If you want json, double check `$this->request_response_type` is returning 'json' and remember it is case sensitive so 'Json' != 'json'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array printed out with **print_r** cannot be parsed back into a variable.

In your server.php do `echo json_encode($_POST);`.
Then in your client.php

```
<?php
//...
$output = curl_exec($curl_handle);

// and now you can output it however you like
if ($this->request_response_type == 'array')
{
    //though i don't see why you would want that as output is now useless if someone ought to be using the variable
    $outputVar = json_decode($output); // that parses the string into the variable
    print_r((array)$outputVar);
    // or even better use serialize()
    echo serialize($outputVar);
}
else if ($this->request_response_type == 'json')
{
    echo $output; //this outputs the original json
}
else if ($this->request_response_type == 'xml')
{
    // do your xml magic with $outputVar which is a variable and not a string
    //xml conversion will be done here later. not ready yet.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look into [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: if he was converting the array in javascript, yes. he is asking about php though.